Python BS4 various HTML tags
I'm trying to reach a particular value while web scraping in Python using BS4. The webpage is https://openaccess.thecvf.com/CVPR2021?day=all
I was able to get the titles by the tag ptitle and shows 1660 which is accurate. But I'm unsure of how to get lower. I used the following to get the titles
    import requests, bs4
    webpage = requests.get(url) #url saved as the above
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, 'html.parser')
    titles = soup.select('dt', {'class' : 'ptitle'})
    print(len(titles) #output is 1660

looks like the remaining tags to traverse are dd > form id > then extract value of each form id of each ptitle to store in a dictionary is my goal.
I've done quite a bit of researching for this and trying to find solutions and everything I've found just produces an error. Don't recall each thing I've tried at this point. Put this down for a bit and just coming back. Seems there are a lot of just do this options but not HTML is done the same so one solution doesn't work for me. Many of the solutions I've found of others asking this people state do this soup.select(tag, tag) or something of the sort which the tags I need to step through are completely different. I've also looked through the BS4 documentation page and tried some of those as well but still produced out of bounds errors or to many arguments or something of the sort. Any help is appreciated.

You can use tag.find_next() to get next <dd> tag with names. Then search for all <form> inside this <dd> tag:
import bs4
import requests

url = "https://openaccess.thecvf.com/CVPR2021?day=all"

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for title in soup.select("dt.ptitle"):
    title_name = title.text
    names = [name.text.strip(" ,\n\r") for name in title.find_next("dd").select("form")]
    print(title_name)
    print(", ".join(names))
    print("-" * 80)

Prints:

...

Data-Free Knowledge Distillation for Image Super-Resolution
Yiman Zhang, Hanting Chen, Xinghao Chen, Yiping Deng, Chunjing Xu, Yunhe Wang
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PluckerNet: Learn To Register 3D Line Reconstructions
Liu Liu, Hongdong Li, Haodong Yao, Ruyi Zha
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Deep Perceptual Preprocessing for Video Coding
Aaron Chadha, Yiannis Andreopoulos
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Explaining Classifiers Using Adversarial Perturbations on the Perceptual Ball
Andrew Elliott, Stephen Law, Chris Russell
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DARCNN: Domain Adaptive Region-Based Convolutional Neural Network for Unsupervised Instance Segmentation in Biomedical Images
Joy Hsu, Wah Chiu, Serena Yeung
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

